# VS2022 community edition won't close

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Just installed VS2022 community edition on Windows 11.  Installed Version 17.3.0 a few days ago and then upgraded to Version 17.4.0.
After upgrading **File>Close Solution** does not close the solution.
**File>Exit** does not exit the application.
Clicking the "X" in the title bar does not close the app.
Everything appears to work normally except closing a solution and closing the app.
The only way to close the app is by stopping the app from task manager or by logging out of windows.
No error messages or notices appear. The app just ignores all attempts to close the solution or exit the app.

Comment: You should report this using the Feedback button in the top-right corner. We aren't Microsoft, sorry.